# Problems with Insert statement

Tags: java, sql, insert

I am trying to insert a record into my Oracle Thin database, and keep getting an invalid syntax exception.  I've looked at the statement and it's parameters till I'm crossed eyed but can't find anything wrong with it.

I am able to connect to the database.  I'm using Java.

Here's the code

```
    public boolean insert(Person person) {
    String sql = "INSERT INTO Person("
            + "FirstName, LastName, Salutation, DateOfBirth, Gender"
            + "Address1, Address2, Address3, City, State, PostalCode)"
            + " VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    try {
        Connection conn = ConnectionFactory.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        stmt.setString(1, person.getFirstName());
        stmt.setString(2, person.getLastName());
        stmt.setString(3, person.getSalutation());
        stmt.setDate(4, person.getDateOfBirth());
        stmt.setString(5, person.getGender());
        stmt.setString(6, person.getAddress1());
        stmt.setString(7, person.getAddress2());
        stmt.setString(8, person.getAddress3());
        stmt.setString(9, person.getCity());
        stmt.setString(10, person.getState());
        stmt.setString(11, person.getPostalCode());
        stmt.executeUpdate();
        return true;
```

Can anyone spot the problem?

As always any help is appreciated!

Tom Magaro

Comment: There is no such thing as an 'invalid syntax exception'. There is `SQLException`, and it has messages and such. Paste the actual error you get. The fact that your code starts with `try` strongly suggests your stack is badly designed. These methods should be declared as `throws SQLException`. If you don't want that (that'd be wrong, but, hypothetically, if you want bad code), then that catch block should have `throw new RuntimeException("unhandled", e);`. It sounds like you are chucking most of the error info. Edit the question with the _complete_ error info. Type and message at least.

Comment: Yeah, I'm new to Java. What I do know, I taught myself. As for the try block, it was suggested when I entered the Connection statement.  I'll check my log and see exactly what the error was. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Under the motto of teach a man to fish, there are some pretty significant problems with how you approach programming.

> I've looked at the statement and it's parameters till I'm crossed eyed but can't find anything wrong with it.

That's not how you do it. There's this perhaps somewhat common, but completely wrong idea that 'good' / experienced programmers just stare at stuff for a while and then jump out of the bath yelling EUREKA!!! as they run down the street naked.

That's movies. Not real life.

Actually good programmers know that mistakes happen all the time and are unavoidable. They don't ever really just stare at things and despair. You start debugging, experimenting, trying simpler programs to double check your understanding.

As an extremely bare minimum act here, for example, you'd.. **print** the SQL statement first. Maybe copy/paste it into an SQL terminal and see what happens. Had you done that, you'd have seen:

```
INSERT INTO Person(FirstName, LastName, Salutation, DateOfBirth, GenderAddress1, Address2, Address3, City, State, PostalCode) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

**And presumably spotted the missing comma between Gender and Address1 fairly easily.**

> Can anyone spot the problem?

Further doubling down on how not to do it. If you're going to spend any time staring at something, stare at the errors you get, not at the code. You seem to disregard errors so much, you didn't even consider it important enough to include in your question, just 'I get a syntax error' is evidently the only conclusion you felt could be drawn from that error and it wasn't worth a second look. But the code, ah, let's stare at it until cross eyed.

Don't do that either. When you don't see the problem in a thing, start debugging it (as in, run a debugger and step through, or add a bunch of print statements, or write something even simpler to check your understanding, or do that work elsewhere ('duplicate') what the code is doing,), and if that doesn't help, stare at something else. Anything else. Such as an error message.

A few more minor design notes on this style:

- Do not catch exceptions unless you know how to handle them. "Print it" or "log it" aren't "handling it". A method named `insert` is *already* yelling off the rooftops: "Hi! I do DB stuff!" - so, it *should* be declared as `throws SQLException`. Just adding a `throws` line for all exceptions in the main body is inappropriate only if an interface forces you not to do it, or the exception has nothing inherently to do with what the method's name, parameters, context, and javadoc say it does (i.e. it would leak abstracted out details). In such cases, your catch block should throw something, and include the exception as second parameter. You don't want code to just continuely blithely on like nothing happened (which is what 'print it' and 'log it' does), and you don't want to deny callers to have a chance at handling things. Maybe *they* can fix it, or maybe they have a better option for reporting it: Let's say this code is used by a web framework, they can for example also log relevant web request stuff, such as an IP. This cannot happen if this code logs it and returns false.
- JDBC is extremely unwieldy and hard to use directly. It wasn't really meant for that, even (it is meant to be a low-level, covers-all-needs-of-all-major-databases, glue layer). Use an abstraction that is designed to write queries in, such as JDBI or JOOQ.
- auto-commit mode is rarely what you want.

Comment: Another design note: use a multiline string (a textblock), then you can embed newlines, which would have prevented the error in the first place.

Comment: It may or may not have, @Charlieface. The problem is that the newline in the code makes it hard to see the lack of comma and multiline wouldn't necessarily prevent it.

Comment: Thanks rwetserfoot, Charlieface is one of those people that think they're all that.  I was programming computers before he was a twinkle in his mother's eye.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there were two problems with the insert.  Thanks to Charlieface for pointing out the missing comma, but the primary reason was Oracle apparently doesn't have AUTO_IMCRECRENT, and I'm not providing a value for the primary key.

Thanks for all your input.

Tom